# initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda8 (why is this message and should I set RESUME)

Tags: boot, bootloader

Mine is a dual boot ASUS running Windows and Ubuntu 19.04. I got the below message on executing apt-get upgrade. Not sure what to do. Pl advice.

```
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda8
I: (UUID=9f45488a-dd0a-45f6-9227-3c76bf5349ca)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

Part of fdisk output:

```
Device   Start        End   Sectors   Size Type


/dev/sda1        2048     923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment

/dev/sda2      923648    1128447    204800   100M EFI System

/dev/sda3     1128448    1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved

/dev/sda4     1161216  204802047 203640832  97.1G Microsoft basic data

/dev/sda5   204802048 1023999999 819197952 390.6G Microsoft basic data

/dev/sda6  1024002048 1419223853 395221806 188.5G Microsoft basic data

/dev/sda7  1419225088 1419227135      2048     1M BIOS boot

/dev/sda8  1920106496 1953523711  33417216    16G Linux swap

/dev/sda9  1419227136 1920106495 500879360 238.9G Linux filesystem
```

The system was just recovered after several GRUB errors and boot-repair.
I don't this innocent looking message to screw up everything again.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want your system to be able to resume or not?

If not, create `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` with the contents:

```
RESUME=none
```

Comment: I forgot my markdown.  Just have one line in the file with 'RESUME=none' (without the single quotes).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I've improved the formatting. In case you weren't sure how to edit: you can edit any of your own posts by clicking the *edit* link that appears under it. [Here's a quick guide to formatting.](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) (You can also [propose edits to improve posts other users wrote](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing). Unlike edits to your own posts, which are applied immediately, those edits will be reviewed by others before being applied. Once you reach [2000 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit), most of your edits no longer require review.)

Comment: Thanks for answering. After quite a bit of deliberation, I attempted to reinstall and ended up repairing Ubuntu installation. That helped reviving things. I am not sure if this is a 'solution' per se and hence did not suggest it as an answer.